# Slow down image transition on background image with jQuery

Tags: jquery

I have created a simple background slideshow using CSS and jQuery. You can see it here and the code is below. http://codepen.io/anon/pen/PwrNyN

This works fine, however I find the current transition into another image too quick and abrupt, and would like to slow this down, so the change is more graceful.

Is this possible to do?

HTML

```
<div class="header">
  <h1>This is some texst</h1>
<div>
```

jQuery

```
var images=new Array(           
    'http://farm3.static.flickr.com/2610/4148988872_990b6da667.jpg',
  'http://farm3.static.flickr.com/2597/4121218611_040cd7b3f2.jpg',
  'http://farm3.static.flickr.com/2531/4121218751_ac8bf49d5d.jpg'
);
var nextimage=0;
doSlideshow();

function doSlideshow(){
    if(nextimage>=images.length){nextimage=0;}
    $('.header')
    .css('background-image','url("'+images[nextimage++]+'")')
    .fadeIn(3000,function(){
        setTimeout(doSlideshow,3000);
    });
}
```

Comment: Change 3000 to something bigger?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just add to .header this:

```
transition: background-image .5s ease-in-out;
```

Comment: Be aware that transitioning background images only works in Webkit for now.

Comment: Thats perfect. Thanks Pebbl for pointing out the webkit issue also, I can live with this, it is an acceptable fall-back.